# Sequelize doesn't insert values into newly added columns

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js, graphql, graphql-js, sequelize-cli

I have `Users` table and I added two new columns `email` and `firstName` to the table through new migration file

```
sequelize db:create --name add_columns_to_users
```

**add_columns_to_users.js:**

```
'use strict';
module.exports = {
  up: (queryInterface, Sequelize) => {

    return [
      queryInterface.addColumn(
        'Users',
        'email',
        {
          type: Sequelize.TEXT,
        }
      ),
      queryInterface.addColumn(
        'Users',
        'firstName',
        {
          type: Sequelize.TEXT,
        }
      )
    ];
  },

  down: (queryInterface, Sequelize) => {
  }
};
```

**user/schema.graphql:**

```
type User {
  id: ID!
  username: String
  email: String
  firstName: String
}

type Query {
  users(id: ID): [User]
}

input CreateUserInput {
  username: String!
  email: String!
  firstName: String!
}

type Mutation {
  createUser (input: CreateUserInput!): User
}
```

And I have the following in my user mutation:

```
Mutation: {
    createUser(root, {input}, context){
    models.User.create(input).then( user => {
        console.log(user);
    });
  }
}
```

This is the input I am sending:

```
{ 
  'username': profile.username,
  'email': profile.email,
  'firstName': profile.firstName
}
```

In my logs, I see values are not being inserted into new columns `email` and `firstName`, whereas it has no problem with old columns like 'username` etc.

```
INSERT INTO "Users" ("id","username","createdAt","updatedAt") VALUES 
(DEFAULT,'Sxxxxh RxxxF','2018-12-04 08:34:11.974 +00:00','2018-12-04 08:34:11.974 +00:00') 
RETURNING *;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So stupid of me! I forgot to add the new columns to the **models/user.js**

**models/user.js:**

```
'use strict';

module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  const User = sequelize.define('User', {
    username: DataTypes.TEXT,
    password: DataTypes.TEXT,
    token: DataTypes.TEXT,
    abbr: DataTypes.TEXT,
    deleted: DataTypes.BOOLEAN,
    email: DataTypes.TEXT,
    firstName: DataTypes.TEXT
  }, {});

  User.associate = function(models) {
  };
  return User;
};
```